# Live Agent, Correct syntax to create Account from the prechat form?

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud, pre-chat, pre-chat-api

I tried to create the account whenever the visitor submits the Prechat form. My guess is that I am not using the correct syntax.I want to populate multiple fields and show the account to the agent when he/she accepts the chat.

This is my snippet from my prechat form.
[image]

Thanks